# Diazo, parameters and restrictedTraverse

Tags: plone, diazo

if in my diazo controlpanel > 'Parameter expressions' I put

```
have_left_portlets = python:context and context.restrictedTraverse('@@plone').have_portlets('plone.leftcolumn',context)
```

I obtain an error only when I'm on the portal homepage:

```
2012-06-26 16:51:42 ERROR plone.transformchain Unexpected error whilst trying to apply transform chain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vito/.buildout/eggs/plone.transformchain-1.0.2-py2.6.egg/plone/transformchain/transformer.py", line 48, in __call__
    newResult = handler.transformIterable(result, encoding)
  File "/Users/vito/.buildout/eggs/plone.app.theming-1.0-py2.6.egg/plone/app/theming/transform.py", line 257, in transformIterable
    params[name] = quote_param(expression(expressionContext))
  File "/Users/vito/.buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.13-py2.6.egg/Products/PageTemplates/ZRPythonExpr.py", line 48, in __call__
    return eval(self._code, vars, {})
  File "PythonExpr", line 1, in <expression>
  File "/Users/vito/.buildout/eggs/AccessControl-2.13.7-py2.6-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/AccessControl/ImplPython.py", line 675, in guarded_getattr
    v = getattr(inst, name)
AttributeError: 'FilesystemResourceDirectory' object has no attribute 'restrictedTraverse'
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: It'd be better if you included full tracebacks for problems like these.

Comment: ok, now with the complete traceback

Comment: What request URL is this error occurring for?

Comment: What is the name of your Plone site and of your theme ? I believe the issue comes from one of thosee. how context.restrictedTraverse('@@plone') can return a plone.resource directory ?

Comment: I tryed also with an istance called "prova" and a theme colled "Plan theme Lazio" /plantheme.lazio . There's always the same error.

Comment: Toutpt: can you explain better your supposition about the plone.resource directory?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a bug in plone.app.theming: the context isn't set correctly. Strange, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just confirming that the issue exits:
I get about the same traceback, the site itself looks fine, but for every click inside the site I get a the following traceback in my instance fg:

```
2012-08-10 15:05:05 ERROR plone.transformchain Unexpected error whilst trying to apply transform chain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/etc/buildout/eggs/plone.transformchain-1.0.2-py2.6.egg/plone/transformchain/transformer.py", line 48, in __call__
    newResult = handler.transformIterable(result, encoding)
  File "/opt/etc/buildout/eggs/plone.app.theming-1.0-py2.6.egg/plone/app/theming/transform.py", line 257, in transformIterable
    params[name] = quote_param(expression(expressionContext))
  File "/opt/etc/buildout/eggs/Zope2-2.13.10-py2.6.egg/Products/PageTemplates/ZRPythonExpr.py", line 48, in __call__
    return eval(self._code, vars, {})
  File "PythonExpr", line 1, in <expression>
AttributeError: 'FilesystemResourceDirectory' object has no attribute 'Language'
```

This is because I have the following line in my manifest.cfg (which is about the same as the parameter line in the plone_control_panel:

```
lang = python: context.Language()
```

In a way in my case this is sort of logical, since not all content objects have an index called Language().

But the 'context' in this case is apparently refering to the 'FileSystemResourceDirectory' and not to the piece of content you are on?
I'll try with pdb if I can find some more info...

Comment: It might be possible to do the same thing (check if there are portlets on the left) with a diazo rule instead of a parameter, like check for the existence of portal-column-one?:

    ... if-content="//*[@id='portal-column-one']"

Comment: right, at the end I also used the css-if condition... but the 'parameter expressions' could be very useful in other user-cases

Comment: Can you try and work out which url exactly is causing the problem? Use the Chrome or Firebug net panel to see the list of requests then visit each individually until you find the offending url. I think I've seens something like this before where a TinyMCE resource made this happen. It needed the X-Theme-Disabled header adding to prevent plone.app.theming from attempting to theme the page.